# Any differences between 0xff and 255, for a "int" variable?

Tags: c#, byte

Are there any differences between coding this :

```
int something = 255;
```

Or this :

```
int something = 0xff;
```

Also : If this variable is casted as `byte` later on, is it still the same?

Comment: Why should there be differences? They are both integers of the same value, just initialized using a different representation. Therefore they'll cast to the same byte value. You can easily see this by declaring both and comparing the equality.

Comment: The only difference between the numeric literals `255` and `0xff` is that these are two different representations of the same number. But this is not always the case. For example the numeric literal `0xffffffff` is still a 32-bit value and thus could fit into an int. However, hex values are treated as unsigned values and thus ``0xffffffff` cannot be assigned to an int without casting. Interestingly, if you do `var v1 = 0xff; var v2 = 0xffffffff;` you will note that v1 is of type int whereas v2 is of type uint; so the whole hex notation thing is a bit context-sensitive (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) with the implied data type (i.e., using `var` assignments) depending on whether a hex value would fit in a given (smallest) type. However the smallest implied type for a hex number literal is a 32-bit type such as int/uint. Not sure though if this is a rule of the C# specification or just a choice of the Visual Studio's C# compiler...

Comment: Update to my last comment: According to C# spec, integer literals (which includes hex notation) can only be of type int, uint, long, and ulong.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb : I saw no differences. I asked because I got worried I might have missed something. Someone had fun switching between both format in our codebase, for apparently no good reason. :/

Comment: That is just notational convenience for humans, the processor sees 0000...011111111 either way.

Answer (score -1):

There's no difference between what I asked about, but there's some obscure reasonning : Since the variable is casted as a `byte` later on, it's the max value for the int.

```
    var v1 = 0xff; //255
    var v2 = 0x100; //256

    Console.WriteLine((byte)v1);
    Console.WriteLine(v1 == (int)v1);
    Console.WriteLine(v1 == (uint)v1);
    Console.WriteLine(v1 == (byte)v1);      

    Console.WriteLine((byte)v2);
    Console.WriteLine(v2 == (int)v2);
    Console.WriteLine(v2 == (uint)v2);
    Console.WriteLine(v2 == (byte)v2);
```

Output :

```
255
True
True
True
0      <--
True
True
False  <--
```

Comment: Indeed, obscure reasoning, such behavior is explained in the docs.

Comment: I stumbled upon this thread whilst trying something where this came to mind.

In C# I was trying to change the color of a light with `255,255,0` to make yellow, but the light would always be red. 

It wasn't until trying `0xFF,0xFF,0` it changes to correct colour, so I'm not sure of why the difference works there but maybe because the types are uint.